# Discrepancy in time difference calculations between PHP, PostgreSQL, and website

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, time-difference

I need to calculate the time difference between two datetime (start datetime: 2023-04-06 09:17:37 and end datetime: 2022-11-17 11:24:30).

I have different results based on a SQL request (PostgreSQL) and PHP and a website. I don't know which one has the right interval.

PHP : https://onlinephp.io/c/e37a4

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2023-04-06 09:17:37');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2022-11-17 11:24:30');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
echo $elapsed;
```

Result :

`0 years 4 months 18 days 21 hours 53 minutes 7 seconds`

---

PostgreSQL : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/va9Zify9F2Gi1T6qUFqs11/0

```
SELECT age('2023-04-06 09:17:37', '2022-11-17 11:24:30')
```

Result :

| age |
| --- |
| {"months":4,"days":18,"hours":21,"minutes":53,"seconds":7} |

---

Website : https://www.timeanddate.com/date/timezoneduration.html?d1=17&m1=11&y1=2022&d2=6&m2=4&y2=2023&h1=11&i1=24&s1=30&h2=9&i2=17&s2=37

Result :

`4 months, 19 days, 20 hours, 53 minutes, 7 seconds`

[image]

Which of the above results is the correct time difference between the two datetimes?

Comment: You should be using `%d` for days, not `%a` https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-examples

Comment: @Nick updated, based on your comment

Comment: Note that ANSI/ISO SQL has no month to second, because months have different number of days. Instead day to second should be used - `'139 20:53:07' days to second(0)`

Comment: Don't you have to give time zone information to Postgresql? The answer you get is according to UTC, i.e. with no DST.

Comment: While working with different timezones, it is good practice to store date-time in the UTC timezone in the database, and while displaying, you can convert it to the respective timezone, which will work fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, they're *all* giving the correct result.

In PostgreSQL, the `age` function does *not* take account of daylight savings time (see the example [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html)).

In PHP, on the sandbox you are using, the default timezone is UTC (check `$datetime1->getTimezone()->getName();`), and so there is no daylight savings involved in the computation.

Thus for both those cases, the time difference is 4 months 18 days 21 hours 53 minutes 7 seconds.

In the website page, you have set the location to Paris. The timezone for Paris (Central European Time) changed to summer time on March 26th, 2023 (the time went forward an hour), and so there is one hour less in the computation of the time difference, and it is 4 months 18 days 20 hours 53 minutes 7 seconds.